# How can I call an API repeatably until the response body has a specific data on Postman?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

Let's say my API call URL is `www.example.com/quiz` with POST method.

And I get the response body like this. And

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();

pm.collectionVariables.set("cv_quiz_order", quiz_order)
if(!jsonData.is_end){
   // TODO: request next question using `quiz_order`
}else{
   // TODO: finish this API and go to the next request.
}
```

When I use `Run Collection`. I want it(the Apis) tests one by one in regular sequence. And only this Api repeats until its is_end is true.

How can I do this?

Comment: This might help you https://community.postman.com/t/how-to-loop-through-array-and-use-its-values-in-a-request/6771

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();

pm.collectionVariables.set("cv_quiz_order", quiz_order)
if(!jsonData.is_end){
  postman.setNextRequest(pm.info.requestName)
}else{
   // TODO: finish this API and go to the next request.
}
```

this will keep sending the same request until is_end is true

postman.setNextRequest allows you to set the next reqeust to be executed , pm.info.requestName gives thecurrent request Name , so you are saying run this request as next request